# Why does a .htaccess protected directory work on http but not on https?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, https

I have a domain `example.com`. `example.com` links to a Tumblr blog. `sub.example.com` links to my home's Ubuntu Server's Apache server. I also have SSL optionally enabled throughout `sub.example.com` (i.e., the user can choose between using `http` or `https` for any webpage). `sub.example.com/directory` is .htaccess protected. I can access the directory perfectly fine on `http://sub.example.com/directory`, but not on `https://sub.example.com/directory`. On the `https` version, I get prompted for my login info. Once I entered my credentials in, I got this error:

`Error: File Not Found
 File Not Found.`

I'm not sure what's going wrong. Below is the full `/var/www/html/directory/.htaccess` file and a selected portion of the `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file.

.htaccess:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /var/www/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

apache2.conf:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I'm on Ubuntu 14.10 and Apache 2.4.10

Answer (score 0):

Try checking these steps below

1. Make sure your HTTPS is working without password.
2. Make sure your .htaccess point to the correct .htpasswd path.
3. I think your apache2.conf is fine but check config files in sites-enabled and conf-available if there any incorrect for port 443.

Comment: HTTPS works fine outside of the protected directory.

The directory is accessible with a password when on HTTP.

Since HTTPS works fine on `sub.example.com`, SSL is (presumably) configured correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Like so many things with computers, a reboot fixed my issues. So, I probably didn't restart some service.